# iOS Convert TouchBegan coordinates to OpenGL ES Coordinates

Tags: ios, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

New to OpenGL ES here. 
I'm using the following code to detect where I tapped in a GLKView  (OpenGL ES 2.0). I would like to know if I touched my OpenGL drawn objects. It's all 2D. 
How do I convert the coordinates I am getting to OpenGL ES 2.0 coordinates, which are seemingly -1.0 to 1.0 based? Are there already built in functions to do so?

Thanks.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    CGRect bounds = [self.view bounds];

    UITouch* touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];

    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    NSLog(@"x: %f y: %f", location.x, location.y);

}
```

Comment: I can do this : *x = ((*x/(bounds.size.width)) * 2.0) - 1.0;
    *y = (((bounds.size.height-*y)/(bounds.size.height)) * 2.0) - 1.0; but seeing this is a frequent task is there a built in function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

-1 to 1 is clipping space. If your coordinate space is in clipping space when it displays on the screen, I'd say you forgot to convert the spaces using a projection matrix. If you're using `GLKBaseEffect` (which I don't recommend later down the road since it tends to memory leak everywhere) then you need to set `<baseEffect>.transform.projectionMatrix` to a matrix that will convert the space correctly. For example,

```
GLKBaseEffect* effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeOrtho(0, <width>, 0, <height>, 0.0f, 1.0f);
self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;
```

`width` and `height` would be the width and height of the device's screen/your `GLKView`/etc. This is automatically applied to the coordinates you pass in so that you can use normal coordinates ranging from 0 to `<width>` on the `x` axis and 0 to `<height>` on the `y` axis, with the origin in the lower left corner of the screen.

If you are using custom shaders like I am then you can pass in the projection matrix as a uniform using:
`glUniformMatrix4fv(shaderLocations.projectionMatrix,1,0,projection.m)`

where `projection` is the matrix and and `shaderLocations.projectionMatrix` is the identifier for the uniform-its name, as they say. You then need to multiply your position by the projection matrix.

Once you've converted away from clipping space, either by passing in the matrix manually or setting the correct property on `GLKBaseEffect`, the only difference between OpenGL space an UIKit space is that the `y` axis is flipped. I convert touches I receive through the `touches` methods and gesture recognizers like this.

```
CGPoint openGLTouch = CGPointMake(touch.x, self.view.bounds.size.height - touch.y);
```

I'll try my best to clarify if you have any questions but keep in mind I'm relatively new to OpenGL myself. :)

Comment: Hi thanks for the detailed explanation. How would I go about using projectionMatrix in my code function touchesBegan above? I just want to check whether the touch happened within the boundaries of an openGL drawing on the screen. Also, upon your warning about GLKBaseEffect, I went to run instruments to check for memory leaks. Have been running for some time and there hasn't been any - perhaps Apple has fixed it in iOS 6.1?

Comment: @Ippier You don't use the projection matrix in `touchesBegan`; you give the projection matrix to your base effect by setting it using the code I specified above. You usually do this wherever you create your `GLKBaseEffect`, like `viewDidLoad`. It prevents you from dealing with clipping space coordinates altogether and lets `GLKBaseEffect` convert screen coordinates into clipping space when it renders. For example, a centered object for a landscape iPhone would have a position of `{240,180}` instead of the bizarre `{0.0,0.0}`. Also, about GLKBaseEffect, they might have fixed it, then.

Comment: I see - so this means that for drawing on the screen, after applying the projectionMatrix to GLKBaseEffect I use the normal coordinates {240, 180} now, correct?

Comment: @Ippier After applying the projection matrix, the coordinate space is identical to what you are used to except for having a flipped `y` axis. The origin is in the lower left corner for OpenGL instead of the upper left like UIKit. The coordinates increase going up the screen, whereas for UIKit the coordinates increase going *down* the screen. Subtract the `y` value of a touch into the height of the GLKView/screen to get the OpenGL equivalent. You can use the last line of code I posted to convert a touch on a UIView into its equalivent in the OpenGL space.

Comment: @Ippier No problem. I know this stuff can be very confusing at times. Also, good job on Tick Tock Trainer! I watched the video on your site and it looks like a nice app. :)